# Is there a way to get around 'setData' on a highcharts area chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a working highcharts area chart, I initialize it with almost no data in its series, just 4 series with one point each. Then I call:

```
function(output){
  var chart = $('#mychart').highcharts();
  chart.series[0].setData(output[0]);
  chart.series[1].setData(output[1]);
  chart.series[2].setData(output[2]);
  chart.series[3].setData(output[3]);
}
```

That works perfectly fine. Later on, the data gets changed and I call that very same function again, and it works, but the problem lies in the amount of time it takes.

I set up logging to log the amount of time that this single function took. The first time it runs it takes about 140ms, the following times when it updates, it takes an average of 2 seconds.

Why does it take so long? Is there a way to speed this up or get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to post this question, but I will leave this answer here for anyone who encounters the same problem:

The problem was the data I was using. In the first iteration, I was using a simple array:

```
[123,912]
```

The rest of the time, I was using an array of objects:

```
[{y: 123},{y: 912}]
```

For some reason, that equates to having a different load speed. From now on, if a fast performance is required, it seems you have to do your part to help highcharts. I hope this helps somebody else who comes across this problem.